# what is the meaning of semantic density per instruction

Tags: cpu-architecture

Can any one tell me the meaning of **semantic density per instruction** and how Register based architecture increases semantic density per instruction ?

Comment: Um, by using less bits to describe the register operand instead of a memory operand? The question is a little vague and I haven't heard of that term, but try reading about CISC vs. RISC

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard the term used before, but I would assume it refers to the complexity and amount of work done per instruction. Instructions like those from the AES-NI extensions found in x86-based architectures will do *a lot* of things internally when executed. Compare that with a classic RISC instruction that can perform an integer add with two registers with operand and one register for the output. It's doing *very little* internally when executed.

I'm not sure why register architectures would specifically increase the "semantic density". I suppose it's possible encode the operands with fewer bits, however the flipside is that you must use more instructions to get your operands into the registers in the first place. Stack architectures require more instructions to achieve similar behaviour to register architectures, but those instruction can be encoded with less space. I guess if you ignore the instruction size then a register architecture can do more work per instruction, but this isn't a very meaningful metric...